# Getting search results from different database tables and displaying them?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, search

I'm trying to create a search function that will retrieve search results for different posters we're creating on our site. If a person is searching for lets say "dog" then it will show the posters which is related to dogs. The site is going to publish different events in the form of posters.

The code looks as following at the moment:

```
<?php

class Search
{
    public static $con;

    private $search = '';

    function __construct()
    { 
        self::$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'guest', 'guestpw', 'db_users');

        $this->search = mysqli_real_escape_string(self::$con, $_POST['search']);
    }

    if(isset($_POST['submit_search']))
    {

    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Event WHERE eventNamn LIKE '%" . $search);

    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Användare WHERE userName LIKE '%" . $search);

    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Poster WHERE Kategori LIKE '%" . $search);

    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM EventTyp WHERE EventTyp LIKE '%" . $search);

    $result = mysqli_query($sql);

    }
}
```

What I want to happen now is to use the search word the user is searching for and then display the events that are associated with that word. 
All help is much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: you replace the variable  $sql each time so only the last will be executed

Comment: First of all you re-assign the `$sql` var over and over again. Then there's the wrong object scope on the search variable (you should use `$this->search` instead).

Comment: What @mplungjan says, each time you give a new meaning to $sql you overwrite it. So the previous one will be 'gone' so when you created your 4th $sql only that one 'exists'.

Comment: You are missing the closing single quote from all variables in queries.

Comment: Consider also using prepared statements -- directly building your query strings like that is unsafe. http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: @mplungjan what do you recommend me to do? Create different variable names for each query? Except this problem, is there anything else that needs to be added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you're having now is not going to work. You're checking for a $_POST request inside a class? I made some adjustments

```
<?php

class Search
{
    public static $con;
    private $search = '';

    public function __construct($search)
    { 
        self::$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'guest', 'guestpw', 'db_users');

        $this->search = mysqli_real_escape_string(self::$con, $search);
    }

    //Do this for every search

    public function search() {
       $sql = mysqli_query(self::$con, "SELECT [column] FROM Event WHERE eventNamn LIKE '%" .       $search . "'".
"UNION ALL ".
"SELECT [column] FROM Användare WHERE userName LIKE '%" . $search . "'".
"UNION ALL".
"SELECT [column] FROM Poster WHERE Kategori LIKE '%" . $search . "'".
"UNION ALL".
"SELECT [column] FROM EventTyp WHERE EventTyp LIKE'%" . $search . "'");
       return mysqli_query($sql);
    } 
}

if(isset($_POST['search'])) {

  $searchClass = new Search($_POST['search']);
  $result = $searchClass->searchEvent();

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Did you mean for me to create a function for each query? Like public function searchName(), searchEvent(), etc?

Comment: Just 3 other function searchAnvändare(), searchPoster() and searchEventTyp();

Comment: @Daan Super Globals are available in any scope, even a class.

Comment: @r3wt Yes thats not what I meant with it. I meant it doesn't look clean.

Comment: @Daan oh, well i agree, but thats not the problem here. The OP doesn't understand PHP yet, but atleast he/she is trying.

Comment: @r3wt True that why I helped him/her.

Comment: I've been using PHP for a 2 weeks now so I'm very confused still, but I really appreciate all the help. Thank you.

Comment: @user3653123 You're making good progress in 2 weeks. Do I need to explain a part in the code?

Comment: @Daan much appreciated. What I'm still confused is that once I've created the functions for each query, how can I then display the results. My problem is that right now it will probably just post the all the search results that are similiar to the search word, but what I want to do is to, once I've found the results that match the search, associate that with the specific event that the word is matched to, and then post that specific event. 
I hope I'm making myself clear, it's still all a bit new to me.

Comment: You could use `UNION ALL` but you need to replace `*` with column names from the database. You only need 1 function here. I've updated my code.

Comment: @user3653123 if you work hard at honing your craft you will do fine. you're alot further along than i was at 2 weeks. good luck

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use `UNION` or `UNION ALL` operator. The SQL UNION operator combines the result of two or more SELECT statements.

```
 SELECT col FROM Event WHERE ...
 UNION ALL
 SELECT col FROM User WHERE ...
```

The document is here:
 MYSQL UNION operator : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

---

Your code could go like this:

```
$sql  = "SELECT [your column] AS event FROM Event WHERE eventNamn LIKE '%" . $search . "'".
    "UNION ALL ".
    "SELECT [your column] AS event FROM Användare WHERE userName LIKE '%" . $search . "'".
    "UNION ALL".
    "SELECT [your column] AS event FROM Poster WHERE Kategori LIKE '%" . $search . "'".
    "UNION ALL".
    "SELECT [your column] AS event FROM EventTyp WHERE EventTyp LIKE'%" . $search . "'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['event '];
  echo "<br>";
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How will I display the search results after using UNION or UNION ALL? And how can I fix the problem of having the $sql variable being replaced? Is this fixing that problem?

Answer (score 0):

1.don't rely on mysqli escape string. use a prepared statement. its faster and foolproof.

2.You can select from multiple tables in one query pretty easily

```
public $mysqli; //make sure your connection is available

public $result = NULL;//setup your result variable
public $search = NULL;
public function getresults() //pass your connection to the object
{
    $search = $_POST["search"]; //post is a super global. no need to pass it by reference

    $result = array();//create an array to store the search results in

    $mysqli = $this->mysqli;//define mysqli so you can access the property of your class object. 

    //construct mysqli in your __construct call, and return it.

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT column1,column2,column3,column4 
                                FROM Event,Användare,Poster,Eventyp 
                                WHERE eventNamn LIKE '% ?';");//prepare our query

    $stmt->bind_param('s', $this->search); 

    //bind our search parameters to the question mark in the query. 
    //if you have multiple querystrings, they must be bound in order.
    if($stmt->execute())//execute prepared statment
    {
        $stmt->bind_result($col1,$col2,$col3,$col4);//bind the selected column results to variables. 
        //these also must be bound in order
        if($stmt->num_rows > 0)
        {
            $result[] = array('type'=> 'success','result' => $stmt->num_rows, 'search string' => $search); //success!
            while($row = $stmt->fetch()) //never use get_result to fetch your statement. always use fetch.
            {
                $result[] = array('type' => 'result', 
                                  'column1' => $col1 ,
                                  'column2' => $col2 ,
                                  'column3' => $col3 , 
                                  'column4' => $col4); //store each result row in an array.
            }
            $stmt->close();//close the connection
        }else{
            $result[] = array('type'=> 'emptyresult','result' => 'No Results Found', 'search string' => $search); //No Results!
        }
    }else{
        $result[] = array('type'=> 'error','result' => 'Error with query', 'search string' => $search); //No Results!
    }
    return $result;//finally return our result for further processing
}
```